# Нужна ли запятая? 3

Tags: пунктуация

После этого возможна разработка национального документа, либо идентичного международному стандарту, либо модифицированного (,) с введением каких-либо национальных особенностей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После этого возможна разработка национального документа — либо идентичного международному стандарту, либо модифицированного, с введением каких-либо национальных особенностей.

Comment: Спасибо :) За тире - отдельное.

Answer (score 0):

После этого возможна разработка национального документа либо **идентичного** международному стандарту, либо **модифицированного**, с введением каких-либо национальных особенностей.

Тире здесь авторский знак, определение луче не обособлять, так как на него падает смысловое ударение.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, обособление (в виде тире или просто запятой) здесь факультативно? Если бы не было союза "либо", обособление было бы обязательно: "документа, идентичного...". Значит, здесь союз играет роль?

Comment: Да,  здесь отсутствие обособления связано с необходимостью переноса ударения на однородные определения, связанные разделительными союзами  Но вообще говоря, в художественной литературе  часто применяется перенос смыслового центра при отсутствии обособления, например:Тянутся мысли неторопливые, дремотные. По дороге зимней, скучной тройка борзая бежит. Я хочу изведать тайны жизни мудрой и простой.